# CPU(central processing unit) & Microprocessor

Tags: cpu-architecture

What is difference between Microprocessor and CPU? Are they the same thing or are used like same thing these days?

[Difference between CPU and Microprocessor](http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-cpu-and-microprocessor)

After readed this article and given responce, the problem was occured that have GPU same features like CPU ?

Comment: we at stackoverflow would appreciate if you did some googling yourself and tell us that you found A and B and that you are confused over C. this question is suitable for answers.com or yahoo.answers.com. show your findings. help us to help you.

Comment: inquisitive I have checkhed them, but I didnt find exactly what I look. Because of this i tried write in here.

Comment: please attach the link of the article that you think the *closest-match* to your expectation. also mention *what* you think is *missing* or *wrong* or *somehow-uncomfortable* about the article. we would certainly fill the gaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that microprocessor is a more general term for any silicon that is capable of processing. By CPU you're referring to the (or one of the) main processing modules within a system. So for, example, a GPU or a DAC are both microprocessors, but not CPUs.